# Finding the parameters with tokens (IndexOf or IndexOfAny)

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, indexing, token

Currently, I was able to get the value of the xpath within my tokens I provided like below

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
{
    while ((CurrentLine = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        int startPos = CurrentLine.IndexOf("{:");
       int endPos = CurrentLine.LastIndexOf(":}");

       if (startPos > 0 && endPos > 0)
       {
           string xPathstr = CurrentLine.Substring(startPos + 2, (endPos - startPos - 2));

           XPathNodeIterator myXPathNodeIterator = myXPathNavigator.Select("/"+ xPathstr);

           while (myXPathNodeIterator.MoveNext())
           {
               Console.WriteLine(myXPathNodeIterator.Current.Value);
               TemplateMemoryBuilder.Append(CurrentLine.Replace(CurrentLine.Substring(startPos, ((endPos + 2) - startPos)), myXPathNodeIterator.Current.Value));
               TemplateMemoryBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
           }

       }
       else
       {
           TemplateMemoryBuilder.Append(CurrentLine);
           TemplateMemoryBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
       }
    }
}
```

I am trying to find a way to get the parameters with the tags if multiple tags are found within a line such as:

```
This is a test to merge item {:/MyTest/TestTwo/Text1:} and {:/MyTest/TestTwo/Text2:} on the same line.
```

Could I use the IndexOfAny method to accomplish this task? I'm not sure how to do this. Program was working fine until I found that this was a possible outcome from a test given to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex to match your tokens. That will make your code a lot more readable.

Example regex and matching code

```
        var regex = new Regex("{:.+?}");
        var input =
            "This is a test to merge item {:/MyTest/TestTwo/Text1:} and {:/MyTest/TestTwo/Text2:} on the same line.";
        var matches = regex.Matches(input);
```

finds two matches without index operations and (costly) string operations.

Comment: That would work, but would this route work since I am reading from a template file where these tokens are located in my document and not directly input?

Comment: You're reading line by line so you can feed your strings into the regex

Comment: how would I feed the string into the RegEx based off the above code?